# python can't connect to drive when converted to exe

Tags: python

``

> import cv2
> import pyautogui
> import numpy as np
> from datetime import datetime
> import os
> import shutil
> import time
> from google.oauth2 import service_account
> from googleapiclient.discovery import build
> from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
> import json
> import threading
>
> Set the screen recording parameters
> SCREEN_SIZE = (1920, 1080)
> FRAME_RATE = 15.0
> output_directory = '.'
>
> Google Drive settings
> CREDENTIALS_FILE = 'credentials.json'
>
> Create the credentials file
> credentials = {
> "type": "service_account",
> "project_id": "screenrecords",
> "private_key_id": "(I have one but I will not put it here for security)",
> "private_key": "I have one but I will not put it here for security",
> "client_id": "I have one but I will not put it here for security",
> "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
> "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
> "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
> "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/mara2366%40screenrecords.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
> "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
> }
>
> with open(CREDENTIALS_FILE, 'w') as f:
> json.dump(credentials, f)
>
> Read the credentials from the credentials file
> creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(CREDENTIALS_FILE)
>
> Read or create the Google Drive folder ID from the config file
> config_file = 'config.txt'
> default_google_drive_folder_id = 'I have one but I will not put it here for security'
>
> if not os.path.isfile(config_file):
> with open(config_file, 'w') as file:
> file.write(default_google_drive_folder_id)
>
> with open(config_file, 'r') as file:
> google_drive_folder_id = file.read().strip()
>
> Verify if the credentials file exists
> if os.path.isfile(CREDENTIALS_FILE):
> print("Credentials file found.")
> else:
> print("Error: Credentials file not found.")
>
> Verify if the config file exists
> if os.path.isfile(config_file):
> print("Config file found.")
> else:
> print("Error: Config file not found.")
>
> Verify if the file names match the actual file names
> if os.path.basename(CREDENTIALS_FILE) != 'credentials.json':
> print("Error: Incorrect credentials file name.")
>
> if os.path.basename(config_file) != 'config.txt':
> print("Error: Incorrect config file name.")
>
> Load the credentials from the credentials file
> with open(CREDENTIALS_FILE, 'r') as f:
> credentials = json.load(f)
>
> print("Loaded credentials:", credentials)
>
> Load or create the Google Drive folder ID from the config file
> if not os.path.isfile(config_file):
> with open(config_file, 'w') as file:
> file.write(default_google_drive_folder_id)
>
> with open(config_file, 'r') as file:
> google_drive_folder_id = file.read().strip()
>
> print("Google Drive folder ID:", google_drive_folder_id)
>
> def record_screen():
> output_file = os.path.join(output_directory, f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')}.avi")
>
> fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
> out = cv2.VideoWriter(output_file, fourcc, FRAME_RATE, SCREEN_SIZE)
>
> while True:
> img = pyautogui.screenshot()
> frame = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
> out.write(frame)
>
> if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
> break
>
> out.release()
> cv2.destroyAllWindows()
>
> def upload_video(video_file):
> try:
> service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
>
> Check if the file already exists in Google Drive
> file_list = service.files().list(q=f"name = '{os.path.basename(video_file)}' and parents in '{google_drive_folder_id}'",
> fields='files(id)').execute()
> files = file_list.get('files', [])
>
> if len(files) > 0:
> If the file exists, update it
> file_id = files[0]['id']
> media = MediaFileUpload(video_file)
> service.files().update(
> fileId=file_id,
> media_body=media
> ).execute()
> print(f"Video '{os.path.basename(video_file)}' updated successfully.")
> else:
> If the file doesn't exist, create it
> media = MediaFileUpload(video_file)
> file_metadata = {
> 'name': os.path.basename(video_file),
> 'parents': [google_drive_folder_id]
> }
> service.files().create(
> body=file_metadata,
> media_body=media,
> fields='id'
> ).execute()
> print(f"Video '{os.path.basename(video_file)}' uploaded successfully.")
>
> return True
> except Exception as e:
> print(f"Error uploading video '{video_file}' to Google Drive:", str(e))
> return False
>
> def main():
>
> Start screen recording process
> recording_thread = threading.Thread(target=record_screen)
> recording_thread.start()
>
> Wait for a few seconds to allow the screen recording to start
> time.sleep(5)
>
> while True:
> video_files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.endswith('.avi')]
> video_files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
>
> if len(video_files) > 1:
> video_files = video_files[:-1]
>
> for video_file in video_files:
> try:
> uploaded = upload_video(video_file)
>
> if uploaded:
> os.remove(video_file)
> print(f"Video '{video_file}' uploaded successfully and deleted.")
> else:
> print(f"Error uploading video '{video_file}'. Retrying in 5 seconds...")
> time.sleep(5)
> except PermissionError:
> print(f"Skipping video '{video_file}' as it is being used by another process.")
>
> if not recording_thread.is_alive():
> break
>
> time.sleep(5)
>
> recording_thread.join()
>
> if **name** == '**main**':
> main()`
> ``

Im expecting it to successfully upload the video to my drive.
before making it into exe it works well